# Using mapbox-gl with d3v4

Tags: mapbox-gl, d3.js

Is it possible to use d3v4 with Mapbox-GL? [This example](https://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/5f4cee0fddc7a64b55a9) works with v3, but I cannot get it working in v4.

In the `mapDraw()` function, I've changed the following lines:

```
//var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint});
var transform = d3.geoTransform({point: projectPoint});

//var path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(transform);

//var featureElement = svg.selectAll("path")
//  .data(geojson.features)
//  .enter()
//  .append("path")
//  .attr("stroke": "red",
//      "fill": "green",
//      "fill-opacity": 0.4
//  });
var featureElement = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(geojson.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.geoPath())
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("fill", "green")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0.4);

//function update() {
//    featureElement.attr("d", path);
//}
function update() {
    featureElement.attr("d", d3.geoPath());
}
```

This produces no errors in the console, but nothing shows up on the map. What am I missing about the conversion to v4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example using d3 v4 and mapbox-gl-js:
https://bl.ocks.org/kmandov/70be1f3b2648ad2be1cdf1feb5afbb4d

[image]

The migration is pretty straightforward. I believe the problem comes from the `update` function. Note that you're calling:

```
featureElement.attr("d", d3.geoPath());
```

where `d3.geoPath()` generates path that does not have the proper projection set. You can fix that by setting the correct projection:

```
featureElement.attr("d", d3.geoPath().projection(transform));
```

However the best approach is to reuse the original path generator to prevent unnecessary object creation on each `update()` call. So just leave the original code untouched:

```
function update() {
    featureElement.attr("d", path);
}
```